# The Matrix Equation $X^{2}=C$

Tags: matrices

Let matrix $C_{n\times‎n}$ and equation $X^{2}=C$ be given, i want to find matrix $X$.

For $n=2$, $X$ is obtained by solving a system of equations;

$$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
x_{11}^2 + {x_{12}}{x_{21}} = {c_{11}}\\
{x_{11}}{x_{12}} + {x_{12}}{x_{22}} = {c_{12}}\\
{x_{21}}{x_{11}} + {x_{22}}{x_{21}} = {c_{21}}\\
{x_{21}}{x_{12}} + x_{22}^2 = {c_{22}}
\end{array} \right. $$

but does analytical method (without solve a system of equations) for solving such equations exist?

Thanks.

Comment: Diagonalization is a possible method.

Comment: @M.Sina firstly you should ask yourself is such a matrix $X$ always exists. I doubt it. Diagonalization won't help if $C$ isn't diagonalizable.

Comment: I second @GitGud's comment. What structure do you have on $C$? For example, $C=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ does not have a square root.

Comment: @copper.hat we dont have any structures on $C$. i want to find some structure on $C$ where $X$ is exists and make a method for find it.

Comment: Where do you take your coefficients? In $\mathbb{R}$, in $\mathbb{C}$,...?

Comment: @julien in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @M.Sina In this case, note that $\det(X^2)=(\det X)^2\geq 0$. So there is no solution for every $C$ such that $\det C<0$.

Comment: @julien: This is true if $\det X$ is real. The matrices here are complex. (Let $X = i$.)

Comment: @copper.hat The OP had just told me that the coefficients were real. Look at the comment above mine.

Comment: @julien: I missed that, the question has $\mathbb{C}$. Maybe the OP should update the question?

Comment: For $n=2$ , someone has done a complete analysis in http://tw.knowledge.yahoo.com/question/question?qid=1010020803771.

Comment: @doraemonpaul: Thank you for the follow-up this question. I have no idea about the language used on this link.

Answer (score 4):

No, an "analytical method (without solve a system of equations)" for solving such equations does not exist. This is because any matrix equation is by definition a system of equations.

However, considering when a matrix is already diagonalized, finding the solution is very simple. Read ahead for some considerations of the non-diagonalizable case.

Every matrix may be orthogonaly reduced to triangular. Take then the equation $Y^2 = R$ where $R$ is triangular and $C=QRQ^*$ where $QQ^*=I$. Then the solution for $X$ may be found

$$X^2=C=QRQ^* = QY^2Q^*$$
So that
$$ X = QYQ^*$$

So it comes down to finding for a triangular matrix. Lets look at the $3 \times 3$ case.
$$\pmatrix{d_0 & 0 & 0 \\ a_1 & d_1 & 0 \\ a_2 & b_2 & d_2}\pmatrix{d_0 & 0 & 0 \\ a_1 & d_1 & 0 \\ a_2 & b_2 & d_2} = \pmatrix{d_0^2 & 0 & 0 \\ a_1(d_0 + d_1) & d_1^2 & 0 \\ a_2(d_0 + d_2) + a_1b_2 & b_2(d_1 + d_2) & d_2^2}$$

This would not necessarily give a result " analytical method (without solve a system of equations)" but it does show that the square root does exist, and there are $2^n$ different solutions, where $n$ is the number of non-zero eigenvalues.

EDIT: I will rollback if this is wrong as it is ripped from a text, but...

**Functions of Jordan Blocks**

For a $k \times k$ Jordan block $J_*$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, and for a function $f(z)$ such that $f(\lambda), f'(\lambda), \dots, f^{(k-1)}(\lambda)$ exist, $f(J_*)$ is defined to be
$$f(J_*) = f\pmatrix{\lambda & 1 \\ & \ddots & \ddots \\ & & \ddots & 1 \\ &&& \lambda}=\pmatrix{f(\lambda) & f'(\lambda) & \frac{f''(\lambda)}{2!} & \cdots & \frac{f^{(k-1)}(\lambda)}{(k-1)!}\\ & f(\lambda)& f'(\lambda)& \ddots & \vdots\\ &  & \ddots & \ddots & \frac{f''(\lambda)}{2!}\\ &  & & f(\lambda)  & f'(\lambda)\\ &  &   & & f(\lambda)\\}$$

Comment: @copper though I suppose your example shows the problem with this when $d_i=0$ for one or more $d_i$. $2^n=0$ in that case though, doesn't it, so no roots exist...

Comment: Why did you assume the square root of a triangular matrix is also triangular?

Comment: I assumed that the square of a triangular is also triangular.

Comment: @ACARCHAU you are correct, the square root need not be triangular. See [jspecter's nice answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/278322/43193) to my question.