# Get the square root of positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know that the square root is defined for positive operators, i.e, a square root of a positive operator $A$ is a self-adjoint operator $B$ satisfying $B^2 = A$

> If $A$ is an arbitrary positive definite matrix $2×2$, then what is $\sqrt A$?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/277047/the-matrix-equation-x2-c/277060#277060) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_2_by_2_matrix).